# How I can calculate sum of some number easily in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have following simple program, but I want to extent it to a larger size. How I can do it much easier in Matlab: here the size of x is 6 but in my real program it has size 500.

```
x=[1 2 4 7 8 9];
y1=x(1);
y2=x(1)+x(2);
y3=x(1)+x(2)+x(3);
y4=x(1)+x(2)+x(3)+x(4);
y5=x(1)+x(2)+x(3)+x(4)+x(5);
y6=x(1)+x(2)+x(3)+x(4)+x(5)+x(6);
m=[y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6];
plot(x,m)
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
plot(x,cumsum(x));
```

`cumsum` does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: the documentation can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html

Answer (score 1):

For the first n elements of *x* you can do:

```
for i=1:n
y(i) = sum(x(1:i));
end
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: I used following, but it did not work it just plot a horizontal line:x=[1 2 4 7 8 9];
for i=1:6
y(i) = sum(x(1:i));
y1=y(i)
end
plot(x,y1,'.r')

Comment: It is not working because you are not doing it right. Your code is printing the variable y1, that is the last value asigned to y, i.e., constant. You should plot the variable y with plot(x,y,'.r').

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of (zeros) y's each of which has an index number.so you may use this index numbers in for loop.    for example:

```
function O=Y(i)
num=0;
for m=1:i
num=num+x(i);
end
O=num;
```

you may use something similar to this.

Comment: It's a good idea to test you code before posting it (or at least be sure it's correct). Where do you initialize `x`? The function won't "see it" unless you include it as an input. Using `i` as a variable name the way you do is not good idea either, since it can be confused with the built-in `i = sqrt(-1)`. You don't need `O = num`, you can just use `num` as output instead. And summing the first `k` numbers in a vector is easier done like this `sum(x(1:k))`, no need for a loop. And the loop doesn't work, since you use `i` as index in `x(i)` when you should have used `x(m)`.